# Discord bot: send message and wait to send another one

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want my bot to send a message then wait like 1-2 seconds before sending another one. I'm using discord.js. I've attempted looking around on the internet and I couldn't find anything for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a piece of code to run after a given duration using [`setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/).

```js
channel.send("First message...")
    .then(() => { // Wait until the first message is sent
         setTimeout(() => {
             channel.send("Second message...");
         }, 2000) // Wait 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds) before sending again.
    })
```